# How much battery does a 3DS use up on standby with streetpass on?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, streetpass

I have my 3DS in my coat when I walk to work, to get play coins and catch any potential street passes on the way in. I'll usually leave it sitting in my coat while I work, so I can take it back out for more at lunch and again at the end of the day.

However it's not clear whether or not I'm using up a lot of battery this way, especially as it's left sitting in my pocket for hours while I just work. Does anyone have any information on how power hungry standby/streetpass are?

Answer (score 5):

According to [this IGN Article](http://ca.ign.com/wikis/nintendo-3ds/New_3DS_XL_vs._3DS_XL_vs._2DS_Comparison_Chart), all versions the 3DS and the 2DS should have a battery life of about three days when in sleep mode.

> Here is a simple chart comparing all the major differences between the three major Nintendo 3DS models:
>
> ```
>     Battery Life    Nintendo 2DS     Nintendo 3DS XL     New Nintendo 3DS XL
>     3DS gaming:     3.5-5.5 hours        3-5.5 hours         3.5-7 hours
>     DS gaming:          5-9 hours         6-10 hours          7-12 hours
>     Sleep Mode:           3 days             3 days              3 days
> ```

You can find an archived copy of the original source [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130921054406/http://cdn02.nintendo-europe.com/media/images/projects/flower/3ds/FAMILY_A4_TABLE_UK.pdf). It appears to have been published by an official Nintendo website, so it should be reliable.

Comment: Also, this will be the estimated time **when the battery is brand new**. Rechargeable batteries lose the ability to retain charge over an extended period of time. It might be a year, it might be 10, but eventually that 2-3 days will move closer to 2-3 minutes.

Comment: Is there any information on sleep mode with wireless communication vs. without though? That seems to be what the OP was asking about.

Comment: @MiloPrice is correct, this info is useful but I'd ideally like to know what difference the wireless communication makes.

Comment: If he wants to get street pass connections, he needs to enable wireless.